# How to use Microsoft Graph to query the User source of authority in Azure B2C

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I'm using Graph to query a user profile in Azure B2C.  I'm able to query the users, but I don't see the Source field to determine the Source of Authority.  What field is this?

[image]

I'm currently using the .28-preview of the Microsoft.Graph.Beta NuGet package.
[image]

And this is what I see in the debugger under Identities:
[image]

How would I tell the difference if that was a Google account or an Azure AD account?

Answer (score 0):

Using Microsoft Graph, it’s the issuerId field within the Identities array and only returns on **beta** version.

Comment: In custom policy, you set the issuer for each identity provider, that’s how you can tell the difference.

Answer (score 0):

`Source` is not included in the [`identities`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/objectidentity?view=graph-rest-1.0) array, and is also not included in the [properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties).

As this [issue](https://www.reddit.com/r/AZURE/comments/6ppq1h/get_azuread_user_source_of_authority_via/) with PowerShell shows, `onPremisesSyncEnabled` property will help.

[image]

Comment: I need to get the name of the source.  Is there another way other than Microsoft graph to get the Source?

Comment: Unfortunately, It seems no other methods to get the source. You could feedback [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/38373556-b2b-please-expose-the-source-property-in-the-gr).

Comment: Make the REST API request manually with HTTPClient.

Comment: @JasSuri Please explain.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by creating a custom attribute and then in the custom policies setting the custom attribute based on signup method (see alternative solution near the end).

How to define custom attributes and use them with the MS Graph API and custom policies is explained pretty well [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-flow-custom-attributes?pivots=b2c-custom-policy). The hardest part is perhaps getting the custom policy right. I did everything in TrustFrameworkExtensions.xml. First defining an "extension_authoritySource" ClaimType:

```
<ClaimType Id="extension_AuthoritySource">
  <DisplayName>AuthoritySource</DisplayName>
  <DataType>string</DataType>
</ClaimType>
```

Then in `<TechnicalProfile Id="Facebook-OAUTH">` I added an OutputClaim which sets this custom attribute to facebook, but this will only be persisted if a PersistedClaim is made in `UserWriteUsingAlternativeSecurityId` as shown below:

```
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_AuthoritySource" DefaultValue="Facebook"/>
```

To persist the custom attribute I added the following to ClaimsProviders:

```
<ClaimsProvider>
    <DisplayName>Azure Active Directory</DisplayName>
    <TechnicalProfiles>
      <TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-Common">
        <Metadata>
          <Item Key="ClientId">[b2c-extensions-app application ID]</Item>
          <Item Key="ApplicationObjectId">[b2c-extensions-app application ObjectId]</Item>
        </Metadata>
      </TechnicalProfile>
    
    <!-- Write data during a local account sign-up flow. -->
    <TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-UserWriteUsingLogonEmail">
      <PersistedClaims>
        <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_AuthoritySource" DefaultValue="local"/>
      </PersistedClaims>
    </TechnicalProfile>

      <TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-UserWriteUsingAlternativeSecurityId">
        <PersistedClaims>
          <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_AuthoritySource" DefaultValue="social"/>
        </PersistedClaims>
      </TechnicalProfile>
  </TechnicalProfiles>
</ClaimsProvider>
```

Note that with the above email signups will always be set as "local", while `UserWriteUsingAlternativeSecurityId` sets it as "social", but is overwritten by the output claim from facebook.

My thinking here is that `UserWriteUsingLogonEmail` is only ever used by email signup, whereas `UserWriteUsingAlternativeSecurityId` could potentially be used by several federated logins, although at the moment I only use facebook.

**Alternative without Custom Attribute**

Alternatively, if you are not using custom policies or cannot use the approach above for another reason, you can use the [MS Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/overview?view=graph-rest-1.0) and look in the "identities" array which contains the sign in type. So for a given user GET: `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/[Users objectID Guid]?$select=identities`

In this array you can find for a local signup:

```
{
  "signInType": "emailAddress",
  "issuer": "[yourdomain].onmicrosoft.com",
  "issuerAssignedId": "[email]"
}
```

and for facebook:

```
{
  "signInType": "federated",
  "issuer": "facebook.com",
  "issuerAssignedId": "[number]"
}
```

Every user also has a "userPrincipalName" item in the identities array so you will have to have some logic to loop through the array and only look for the signInType which you want to support. Yet another reason for preferring using custom attribute and setting the authority source yourself.